# Trouble in setting JDK path in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 with API level 27 and Windows 8 (32-bit).
I am getting this error:

> Create Process error = 216 problem

I resolve it by doing

> File -> Project Structure -> Unchecked Used Embedded  JDK -> Set My JDK Path -> Try Again

But it is not working and the **Unchecked Embedded JDK again gets checked** and my **JDK path is not set**.

Comment: Have you set the environment variables for your jdk?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to uncheck the option to use embedded JDK, then set the following attribute in `gradle.properties` located usually in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle`for Windows:

**-Xmx768m** or use a lower memory value like **-Xmx512m**